# css @font-face doesn't work at all

Tags: css, font-face

I need to embed a font to a website via `@font-face`. I followed some tutorials with the result that it doesn't work for me.

**CSS:**

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'GESSTwoLightRegular';
    src:url('../fonts/ge_ss_two_light-webfont.eot'); 
    src: url('../fonts/ge_ss_two_light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('../fonts/ge_ss_two_light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/ge_ss_two_light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), 
         url('../fonts/ge_ss_two_light-webfont.svg#gess') format('svg'), 
         url(ge_ss_two_light-webfont.otf) format('opentype');
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: Have you declared the correct font-family in your CSS? We will need some more info to help you with your problem. Perhaps you can give us the link to the website.

Comment: As trickeedickee stated, you need to use the `GESSTwoLightRegular` in a `font` call on the `body` or whatever element you are using it on. Also, be sure the font files exist in the location you specify in your `url` path.

Comment: Really hard to test this without access to the font or knowing what platform/browser is failing....

Comment: you can access in this url http://www.grat.ly/3/index.html, i testing it on firefox and chrome and safari on mac os x, and i call it in the selector as the font-family declared

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://fontface.codeandmore.com/

Up load  font that you want to use in font face and then this program will generate css and all font type.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question. It does not even fix arabic font-embedding problems.